# MVC 4 Jquery Datepicker Initializes on Multiple Separate Threads

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using VS2010, MVC 4 with Razor, JQuery 1.8/JQueryUI 1.10.3 and AJAX in am AnyCPU web app.  I'm seeing really odd behavior where the initialization of a JQueryUI datepicker runs on 3-4 separate threads outside of my control.  I discovered this because the app accesses HttpContext.Current.Session in the master layout and it appears that each of the 'datepicker init threads' refers back to or loads the master layout and on one of the threads it throws an object reference exception.

Inspecting this request on Fiddler/Dev Tools does not show mutltiple requests although the threads make it look like there are multiple requests since the rendered partial in the master layout is the one calling HttpContext.Current.Session.

Note that only my views with the datepicker control behave this way, all others have a single thread and the Session object is accessible without issue.

I have nested layout views with various rendered partials and included bundled/minified Jquery files.

```
------------------
| master layout (only ref'd by secondary layout)
|
|   - bundled/min Jquery/JqueryUI js references
|   - rendered partial view that accesses HttpContext.Current.Session
|
|   ------------------
|   | secondary layout (only ref'd by View)
|   |
|   |   - Jquery with datepicker control init function (outside of document.ready)
|   |   
|   |   ------------------
|   |   | View
|   |   |
|   |   | - Jquery inside document.ready that calls datepicker control init function (included in secondary layout) based on values in this view's model
|   |
|
```

I've tried variations of the above, including putting all of the markup, js refs, etc onto a single page and it still behaved the same.  I can post actual code if needed, but wanted to get this out there as I'm in a bind.

Comment: No one else has experienced this?  Why do I always encounter the odd things?  To quote C-3PO, "seems to be my lot in life".

Comment: Could not recreate this on a different machine, could just be a localized occurrence.